# Consider P(n). Show that it is true for n > 2 given the two statements below are true...

Tags: elementary-number-theory, formal-proofs

*For every natural number n, consider P(n) a statement. Prove that if the following two statements are true:

1) for all n ∈ N, P(2^n);

2) for all n > 2, P(n) ⇒ P(n − 1);

then P(n) is true for all natural numbers n ≥ 2.*

Other questions ask you to use the method to solve this problem, and I want to make sure I'm using the best method, even though I think the method I used works, I'm wondering the best solution.

My method:
For x=2, P(2^2) = P(4), and P(4)⇒P(3), thus P(3) (minimum case).
Then for i ∈ {1,...,∞}, given P(2^(n+1)), Because P(n)⇒P(n-1), P(x) for all X between P(2^n) and P(2^(n+i)) is true, and since 2^(n+i) goes to infinity as i does, P(x) is true for all x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that works.
You can note that $P(n)$ implies $P(n-1)$ means $P(n)$ implies $P(m)$ for all $m \leq n$.
Then for any particular natural number $p$, choose $2^q \geq p$. Then we have $P(2^q)$ is true so $P(p)$ is true.